# How to store listview arrays in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, arrays, listview

im working on a project in which i have a listview and i have few arrays in my code but i want to load arrays from a separate xml file which is "strings.xml"

but i cannot figure out how to do it

here is my activity

```
package com.Example.myapk;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private ListView list1;

 private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

 "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4","item 1",       "item 2", "item3", "item 4"};

 EditText inputSearch; 
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); 
 list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView01);
 adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
  list1.setAdapter(adapter);
  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
// When user changed the Text
MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key",position);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
 });   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in you string.xml

```
<string-array name="myArray">
   <item >Iphone</item>
   <item >Tutorials</item>
   <item >Gallery</item>
   <item >Android</item>
   <item >item 1</item>
</string-array>
```

Then `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray)` will return those values as an array of strings. So in your main activity file

```
private ListView list1;
private String array[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
EditText inputSearch; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); 
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView01);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: to get String array from xml to your code, use below code `getResources().getStringArray(R.id.myArray);` which will gives you string array

Comment: but i already have few arrays in my code , do i need to remove them? i tried to do it but i get errors  ,can you modify my code instead?

Comment: please tell me where do i implement this in my code?? i dont want to mchange the whole code , just the array thing. please tell clearly 1.what should i remove from my code? 2.Where should i add your code in my code ?

Comment: Simply reply `private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4","item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4"};
` code with

 `private String array[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.myArray);` and put string array in `string.xml`
Let me know still if you have any query

Comment: here my xml file is Arrays.xml

Comment: what is name of your array in xml file. here in this example i have putted  `myArray` name in string.xml  `<string-array name="myArray">`

Comment: then inserted the code private String array[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.myArray); in my java file like you said but im getting error on R.id.myarray

Comment: you put the `R.id.yourarrayname` array name which you have supplied in string.xml

Comment: Arrays.xml in the values folder

Comment: what do you mean by yourarrayname?  my xml file is "Arrays.xml"

Comment: in your Arrays.xml file check `<string-array name="myArray">` this line where you can see array name

Comment: yes yes i copied your code and pasted in my xml file and it is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myArray">
        <item>Iphone</item>
        <item>Tutorials</item>
        <item>Gallery</item>
        <item>Android</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

Comment: sorry , i forgot to change this, use this `R.array.myArray` instead of `id` use `array`

Comment: i think eclipse only picks up id's from Activities, not from xml files

Comment: sorry , i forgot to change this, use this R.array.myArray instead of id use array

Comment: ok i changed it to (R.array.myArray); but now im getting error on "array"

Comment: Please check code is saved properly and and compiled. for time being you can comment error line and clean the project. so that string.xml file array get registered in R.java class file.

Comment: HELP! my app is force closing

Comment: either you can modify your existing question with this code or you can create new question for this.

Comment: NUll Pointer Exception is generally occurred when you haven't initialized your variable or object. try to find error line where your project package name is there and send that line

Comment: please open this link and copy paste the log in notepad cus im going to delete it

Comment: where ? send me code at line 19 of your MainActivity.java class

Answer (score 0):

To store your array in xml, you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="myArray">
        <item>Iphone</item>
        <item>Tutorials</item>
        <item>Gallery</item>
        <item>Android</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then in your code, you can access it:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

Check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 0):

In your **strings.xml**

Iphone
    Tutorials
    Gallery
    Android

Add more items if you want.

**In your code:**

```
package com.Example.myapk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list1;

    EditText inputSearch;
    **ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;**

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView01);
        **adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,               R.array.menu, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);**
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        WebViewActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", position);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error on (getActivity() "the method getactivity() is undefined for the type main activity"

Comment: Sorry, this method getActivity() means that you are in a fragment and want the activity reference. Since you are in activity, change getActivity() for this